# XSD validation expects element that it's complaining about

Tags: xml, soap, xsd, soapui, xml-validation

I am having a weird problem on a SOAP response validation. I've hacked down the response and the XSD to the minimum required to reproduce the error. The XSD:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xs:schema targetNamespace="http://peoplesoft.com/rootResponse" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="root">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" name="ReturnID" />
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

The SOAP response:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <soapenv:Body>
    <root xmlns="http://peoplesoft.com/rootResponse">
      <ReturnID />
    </root>
  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

If I validate the original response in soapUI, it says **Expected element 'ReturnID' instead of 'ReturnID@http://peoplesoft.com/rootResponse' here in element root@http://peoplesoft.com/rootResponse**.

When I load the above files in Visual Studio 2012 (yes, I do tell Visual Studio to use this XSD file to validate the namespace), I get this: **The element 'root' in namespace 'http://peoplesoft.com/rootResponse' has invalid child element 'ReturnID' in namespace 'http://peoplesoft.com/rootResponse'. List of possible elements expected: 'ReturnID'.**

In both cases, it's squawking about the **ReturnID** element, yet it says it expects the **ReturnID** element?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless you are dealing with very unusual instance documents, which you aren't, your xs:schema element should carry the attribute `elementFormDefault="qualified"`. Without this, a local element declaration (such as that for ReturnID) refers to an element in no namespace, rather than an element in the target namespace.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, the xml validator wants

<del>ReturnID</del>

```
<ReturnID xmlns="http://peoplesoft.com/rootResponse" />
```

to be

<del>ReturnID xmlns="http://peoplesoft.com/rootResponse"</del>

```
<ReturnID />
```

Change the document as follows:

```
<ps:root xmlns:ps="http://peoplesoft.com/rootResponse">
  <ReturnID />
</ps:root>
```

**Edit**
The reason is that by specifying `root xmlns="http://peoplesoft.com/rootResponse"` on your document, all inner elements will then assume this namespace as well.

Comment: Thanks, but one question: if I change `xmlns` to `xmlns:ps` and don't change `ReturnID` to `ps:ReturnID`, the validation error still goes away. Why is that? I thought if you defined a new namesapce, you had to explicitly specify it in all uses of it?

Comment: @ArenCambre - Apologies my mistake - I'll edit - I didn't read the error message properly :(